# Swift: Scanner scanDouble doesn't work correctly

Tags: swift, parsing, swift5, nsscanner

I am working on String parse in swift and I use Scanner.
But the main problem is that scanner.scanDouble and scanner.scanFloat doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
var magnitude: Double = 0
let scanner = Scanner(string: magString) // magString sample values  are "E1.00 INCH", "E1.50 INCH", "M0.88 INCH"

scanner.scanDouble(&magnitude)
```

But after running app, magnitude is 0.0

How can I get 1.00, 1.50 and 0.88 from string?

Comment: I already added sample value - "E1.00 INCH", "E1.50 INCH", "M0.88 INCH"

Comment: I just edited post. At first, I just added sample string value of arr[4]. There maybe some confusing between you and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanDouble` chokes on the "E" and "M" prefixes. If your know what these are, you can add them to the ignore list:

```
for str in ["E1.00 INCH", "E1.50 INCH", "M0.88 INCH"] {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: str)
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "EM")
    var magnitude = 0.0
    if scanner.scanDouble(&magnitude) {
        print(magnitude)
    }
}
```

or, if you know it's only one leading character, remove it using `dropFirst`:

```
for str in ["E1.00 INCH", "E1.50 INCH", "M0.88 INCH"] {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: String(str.dropFirst()))
    var magnitude = 0.0
    if scanner.scanDouble(&magnitude) {
        print(magnitude)
    }
}
```

also, you should check the return value of `scanDouble`. BTW, this method is deprecated as of iOS 13.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but "E1.00 INCH", "E1.50 INCH", "M0.88 INCH" are only sample string. The first character can be other Alphabetic characters- "D" or "B". But the clear thing is that the first character is Alphabetic character and second string is numeric, and last word is "INCH". Can you provide me other solution based on this?

Comment: If you _know_ it's only one character, use `dropFirst`.

Comment: OK, let me try!

Comment: Great answer! It works perfectly. Thanks for your help!